# Using .is() target Off-canvas Nav Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating an off-canvas nav that closes on three conditions:

1. The user toggles the nav button
2. the user clicks a link inside the nav
3. the user clicks anywhere but the nav when the nav is open.

I've got the first two conditions working but not the third. Below is my code. What I'm trying to accomplish is essentially the following:
check for a click on the body and if that click is the (in this case) .pageContainer run a second check to see if the nav has the class "showMenu" and the flag is == true

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var button = $('.button');
 var ocn = $('.ocn');
 var test = $('.test');
 var flag = false;
 
 //toggle menu using just the button
  button.click(function() {
   if ( flag == false ) {
    ocn.addClass('showMenu');
    flag = true;
   } else {
    ocn.removeClass('showMenu');
    flag = false;
   }
  });
 
 //close the menu clicking on a link
 test.click(function() {
  ocn.removeClass('showMenu');
  flag = false;
 });
 
 //close menu when click off canvas
 
  /*
  $('body').on('click', '.pageContainer', function(e) {
  
  if( ocn.hasClass('showMenu') && flag == true) {
   ocn.removeClass('showMenu');
   flag = false;
  }
  
 }); 
 */
 
 
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.ocn {
 position: absolute;
 left: -300px;
 top: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: #ccc;
 transition: left .2s ease;
 z-index: 2;
 border: 1px solid;
}

.showMenu {
 left: 0px;
}

.pageContainer {
 height: 500px;
 width: 1000px;
 border: 1px solid;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.button {
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 border: 1px dashed;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 left: 400px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.test {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ocn">
 <p class="test">here is some text for the menu</p>
</div>
<div class="pageContainer">
 <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error you are encountering?

Comment: Can you give the correct `html` as we cant work with what you have given now ?

Comment: All set.  My apologies I copied the wrong code into the HTML area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `e.target` property to compare what was clicked. Similar to this:

```
if(e.target == pageContainer[0])
```

You can now apply the required logic when `.pageContainer` was clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pageContainer = $('.pageContainer');
  var button = $('.button');
  var ocn = $('.ocn');
  var test = $('.test');
  var flag = false;

  //toggle menu using just the button
  button.click(function() {
    if (flag == false) {
      ocn.addClass('showMenu');
      flag = true;
    } else {
      ocn.removeClass('showMenu');
      flag = false;
    }
  });

  //close the menu clicking on a link
  test.click(function() {
    ocn.removeClass('showMenu');
    flag = false;
  });

  //close menu when click off canvas
  $('body').on('click', '.pageContainer', function(e) {
    if (e.target == pageContainer[0]) {
      //console.log('pageContainer was clicked')
      if (ocn.hasClass('showMenu') && flag == true) {
        ocn.removeClass('showMenu');
        flag = false;
      }
    };
  });





});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ocn {
  position: absolute;
  left: -300px;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: left .2s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.showMenu {
  left: 0px;
}

.pageContainer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px dashed;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ocn">
  <p class="test">here is some text for the menu</p>
</div>
<div class="pageContainer">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand the logic here, but the code doesn't execute.

Comment: the menu validation is executed, closing the menu if it is open, when you click on `.pageContainer` that is what you wanted no?

Comment: My apologies, I made a mistake. Yes it is, can I ask a further question?